# Compilation error passing class template as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I wrote code like below:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class myTemplateClass
{
public:
    myTemplateClass(T t)
        : val{t}
    {}
    T val;
};

template <template<typename> class TT, typename T>
auto create(T val)
requires std::is_same_v<TT<T>, myTemplateClass<T>>
{
    return TT<T>(val);
};


int main()
{
    auto result =  create<myTemplateClass<int>>(10);
    // or
    auto result = create(static_cast<int>(10));
}
```

But both of the `create` function calls has failed to build.

Error for the 1st call (on MSVC):

> error C2672: 'create': no matching overloaded function found
> error C3207: 'create': invalid template argument for 'TT', class > template expected

Error for the 2nd call (on MSVC):

> error C2672: 'create': no matching overloaded function found
> error C2783: 'auto create(T)': could not deduce template argument for 'TT'

I expected the following to compile:

```
    auto result = create(static_cast<int>(10));
```

Comment: You should specify template template argument as `create<myTemplateClass>(10)`.

Comment: `myTemplateClass` is a class template (there are not template classes) and `myTemplateClass<int>` is a class.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], provide that along with the error it produces.

Comment: In order to improve your question, please add the exact error messages you get for each function call.

Comment: I added the specific errors for the errounous calls that I get on MSVC. @yibruce please edit it and update if you use another compiler.

Answer (score 1):

`create` is dependant on 2 template parameters: `TT` and `T`.
Therefore one way to do what you want is to mention them explicitly:

```
//-------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--vvv-----
auto result = create<myTemplateClass, int>(10);
```

An altenative way (in which the `int` is deduced) is mentioned in the comment above (by @songyuanyao):

```
auto result = create<myTemplateClass>(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

##### With

```
template <template<typename> class TT, typename T>
auto create(T val)
requires std::is_same_v<TT<T>, myTemplateClass<T>>;
```

Way to call it would be

```
create<myTemplateClass>(42);
create<myTemplateClass, int>(42);
```

##### To allow

```
auto result =  create<myTemplateClass<int>>(10);
```

You would need:

```
template <typename TT, typename T>
auto create(T val)
requires std::is_same_v<TT, myTemplateClass<T>>
{
    return {val};
}
```

##### To allow

```
auto result =  create(10); // myTemplateClass<int>
```

You would need:

```
template <typename T>
auto create(T val) -> myTemplateClass<T>
{
    return {val};
}
```

##### Note

Notice that `create` (std uses `make_xx` as `std::make_optional`/`std::make_pair`/...) is not really needed with CTAD (C++17), you might write:

```
auto result =  myTemplateClass(10); // myTemplateClass<int>
```